# Cant find shortcuts in the desktop folder on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7 won't boot on my computer anymore, so I booted from a Knoppix Live CD to recover my data.

I'm looking at the contents of Users/username/Desktop folder but there are no shortcut (.*lnk) files at all.  All the other files are there, just not the shortcuts. I know I have several shortcut icons on my desktop and they all displayed fine. I also checked the other folders such as All Users, Public, and default but I can't find them. Where are they?

Comment: Have you checked \Users\Public\Desktop?  Note that the folder is hidden by default, so you'll need to show hidden files/folders to see it.

Comment: Yes, nothing there either.

Comment: If you right-click a shortcut on your desktop, the General tab will tell you where the physical .lnk file is located.

Comment: As matter of fact my problem is that Windows is crashed and it wont start so I am accessing my files through a live CD.

Comment: Is it a live WinPE CD?  If so, what shows up as the C: drive in the PE environment may not be the same C: drive that Windows (formerly) booted from.  So check to see if you have a D: or E: drive.  Your files might be there.

Comment: Its knoppix and Im looking at the right place. I can see the folders and other files I have on my desktop but not the shortcut icons for some reason.

Comment: I edited your question to include this information.

Comment: What is the POINT in seeing lnk files?  Even if they were there.. what good would that do?

Comment: *What is the POINT in seeing lnk files?* Indeed. Here we're totally in agreement. Desktop shortcuts serve no other purpose than to point to actual (executable) files in this case. You're just recovering data from a non-working Windows, not running it. The files you're asking about would only be useful if actually running that Windows.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, Shortcuts can point to *any* file, and they can contain a custom working directory and parameters too. Maybe OP has shortcuts to deeply-nested directories or files that they can't remember the location of. Or maybe they had carefully configured shortcuts that they need to recover launch parameters from.

Comment: @Romen Maybe, for you an me (unintended rhyme). Not the case here because users who do that don't post questions such as this (and won't use an old Knoppix CD(!!) to this kind of jobs) ;)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, So you'd rather say that the OP's question is a pointless exercise based on *assumptions* of their computer skill level? While we're making any assumptions, you could also assume that that old Knoppix CD is the *only bootable media they had*.

Comment: @Romen Searching for desktop shortcuts in this scenario is pointless regardless of other considerations even in the extreme case you described above. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @CainNuke, We need some more information to find out why those `.lnk` files are missing. What kind of shortcuts were they? What version of Knoppix is it? Can you try any other bootable Linux or [WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro) which was mentioned above? @GabrielaGarcia is right in pointing out that *most* shortcuts are trivial and are easily replaced. You shouldn't have to pursue this problem any further unless those shortcuts were manually created with custom launch arguments or something else that was customized in their properties.

Comment: Those 2 hispanic users are only wasting my time. Its irrelevant to ask why I want something, I WANT IT and thats all it matters. I want to have my desktop EXACTLY the way I had it before Windows crashed. Thats it, as simple as that. I have Knoppix latest version but I think thats irrelevant too since a Live CD shows you exactly what you have in that folder so if it doesnt show the ink files it simply means they are NOT THERE but I want to know why is that.